# The tag "on-topic" should be synonyms of the tag "scope"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, meta

On our **meta** site, there are two different tags [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) but actually [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) is synonyms of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). Refer [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was already a suggested synonym which I have now approved. I also removed the [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) tag from the three questions that had it.

So, [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) is now a synonym of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).